# PHP Cassandra and CodeIgniter Error No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [10061]

Tags: php, cassandra

Does anybody knows about PHP CodeIgniter and cassandra? I have download the phpcass from [PHPCassa](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa).

**ERROR**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'NoServerAvailable' with message 'An attempt was made to connect to every server twice, but all attempts failed. The last error was: exception 'TException' with message 'TSocket: Could not connect to 192.168.0.1:9160 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [10061])' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\thrift\transport\TSocket.php:229 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\thrift\transport\TFramedTransport.php(83): TSocket->open() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\connection.php(71): TFramedTransport->open() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\connection.php(220): ConnectionWrapper->__construct('fifthdi', '192.168.0.1:916...', NULL, true, 5000, 5000) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\connection.php(256): ConnectionPool->make_conn() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\connection.php(350): Connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSIgniter\application\libraries\phpcassa\connection.php on line 231

Here is the cassandra.php code

```
$servers[] = '192.168.0.1:9160';//If omitted, the port defaults to 9160.
//$servers[] = '127.0.0.2:9160';
//$servers[] = '127.0.0.3:9160';
$config['cassandra_servers'] = $servers;
$config['keyspace'] = "fifthdi";
$config['default_cf'] = "Standard1";
//set of column families your application uses and you want to have initialied and cached
$config['init_cf'] = array("Standard1"); //set of configs to initalize by default
$config['max_retries'] = 5;
$config['send_timeout'] = 5000;
$config['recv_timeout'] = 5000;
$config['recycle'] = 10000;
//if needed then array("username"=>user1,"password"=>pass); replaces NULL
$config['credentials'] = NULL;
$config['framed_transport'] = true;
```

Comment: You'll need to give more information. For example, show us the code that triggers this problem.

Comment: What port is cassandra listening on. That sort of error usually means either the database service is not started or you are trying to connect to the wrong port

Comment: @Riggs Cassandra listening on the port no 9160

Comment: Is 192.168.0.1 the machine you are on or another PC on your network? Regardless, make sure you have set the firewall to allow access to port 9160

Comment: @Riggs firewall of my PC is allready turnoff